# non-standard exponential-squared fog attenuation

Tags: logarithms, roots

I inherited a formula that I'm hoping to simplify.

$d = \frac{\sqrt{-\log_2(t)}}{f\sqrt{\ln(2)}}$

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jason

EDIT (for context):
This formula determines the exponent for exponential-squared fog attenuation.  **d** stands for density, which is usually not so complicated, and the typical final usage is:

$\frac{1}{e^{{distance * density}^2}}$

Comment: how do you want it simplified? what variable do you want to solve for?

Comment: also, is $t$ always less than $0$?

Comment: 0 < t <= 1, f > 0, and I'd like to solve for d.  Based on data, I suspect the logs can be factored out somehow, but can't seem to prove it.

Comment: try to use MathJax in comments too, if you could.

Comment: rewriting the numerator in the root as $-\frac{\ln t}{\ln 2}$ and then using the square root to get $fd\ln2=\sqrt{-\ln t}$ is about all you could do, I fear.

Comment: thank you count, i should have thought of that...gets me to the same base at least.

Comment: no sweat. i forget tricks like that all the time. happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use:
>
> - $$\log_x(y)=\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(x)}$$
>
>   ---

So:

$$\text{d}=\frac{\sqrt{-\log_2(t)}}{\text{f}\sqrt{\ln(2)}}=\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{\ln(t)}{\ln(2)}}}{\text{f}\sqrt{\ln(2)}}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{-\ln(t)}}{\sqrt{\ln(2)}}}{\text{f}\sqrt{\ln(2)}}=\frac{\sqrt{-\ln(t)}}{\text{f}\ln(2)}$$